# How to add elements to a vector of pairs every 3rd line?

Tags: c++, vector, fstream, getline, std-pair

I'm trying to make a vector of pairs from a text that looks something like that:

*line1* 
*line2* 
*line3*

And the vector would contain a pair of `line1` and `line2`.

And another vector would contain `line1` and `line3`

Normally I would add lines to a vector like this

```cpp
    vector<string> vector_of_text;
    string line_of_text;

    ifstream test_file("test.txt");

    if(test_file.is_open()){
        while(getline(test_file, line_of_text)){
            vector_of_text.push_back(line_of_text)
        }

        test_file.close();
    }
```

but I don't know if it is possible to access the next line of text with the `getline` command.

For example, in an array, I would do `i+1` or `i+2` for the next or 3rd element.
I was wondering if there was a way to do that with `getline`.

Comment: Where would the fourth line go and what would that pair contain? How many `vector<pair<string,string>>` do you want to have? Please give a few more lines of input and the expected output to give us a little more context.

Comment: @TedLyngmo so i would like to have two vectors of pairs, one would contain a pair of line1 and line2 and the second vector would have line1 and line3, and then for 4th, 5th and 6th line and every another 3 would be line4 and line5 in the first vector, and line4 with line6 in the second vector and that goes for the rest of the text. i hope that clears that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want two `vector<pair<string, string>>`.

This could be one way:

```
// an array of two vectors of pairs of strings
std::array<std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>>, 2> tw;

unsigned idx = 0;

std::string one, two, three;

// read three lines
while(std::getline(file, one) && 
      std::getline(file, two) &&
      std::getline(file, three))
{
    // put them in the vector pointed out by `idx`
    tw[idx].emplace_back(one, two);
    tw[idx].emplace_back(one, three);

    // idx will go 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 ... until you can't read three lines anymore
    idx = (idx + 1) % 2;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cTnYM1onr)

Comment: Thanks @TedLyngmo. As always, your answer helps a lot. It has helped me as well

Comment: @Pat.ANDRIA Oh, thank you! Glad it helped!